# How to correctly use InitWindow in Objective-C OpenGL?

Tags: objective-c, c, opengl, freebsd

What am doing wrong ?
I am trying to learn OpenGL and Objective-C, i am porting it code from C to Objective-C.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#define WINDOW_TITLE_PREFIX "Chapter 1"

int CurrentWidth = 800,
    CurrentHeight = 600,
    WindowHandle = 0;

void Initialize(int, char*[]);
void InitWindow(int, char*[]);
void ResizeFunction(int, int);
void RenderFunction(void);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Initialize(argc, argv);

    glutMainLoop();

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void Initialize(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    InitWindow(argc, argv);

    fprintf(
        stdout,
        "INFO: OpenGL Version: %s\n",
        glGetString(GL_VERSION)
    );

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}

void InitWindow(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitContextVersion(4, 0);
    glutInitContextFlags(GLUT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);

    glutSetOption(
        GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE,
        GLUT_ACTION_GLUTMAINLOOP_RETURNS
    );

    glutInitWindowSize(CurrentWidth, CurrentHeight);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);

    WindowHandle = glutCreateWindow(WINDOW_TITLE_PREFIX);

    if(WindowHandle < 1) {
        fprintf(
            stderr,
            "ERROR: Could not create a new rendering window.\n"
        );
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glutReshapeFunc(ResizeFunction);
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderFunction);
}

void ResizeFunction(int Width, int Height)
{
    CurrentWidth = Width;
    CurrentHeight = Height;
    glViewport(0, 0, CurrentWidth, CurrentHeight);
}

void RenderFunction(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

I got this code from  http://openglbook.com/the-book/chapter-1-getting-started/

I've done this but i am no realy sure what is the error i think the problem is with pointers.

header.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <stdio.h>
#import <string.h>
#import <GL/glew.h>
#import <GL/freeglut.h>
#define WINDOW_TITLE_PREFIX "test gl objective c"

@interface princ : NSObject {
    int CurrentWidth;
    int CurrentHeight;
    int WindowHandle;

}

-(void)InitValues;
-(void)ResizeFunction;
-(void)RenderFunction;
-(void)InitWindow: (int)argc: (char*[])argv:(void*)FoundRZ:(void*)FoundRD;
-(void)Initialize: (int)argc: (char*[])argv;

@end

@implementation princ 

-(void)InitValues {

    CurrentWidth = 800;
    CurrentHeight = 600;
    WindowHandle = 0;
}

-(void)ResizeFunction {

    int Width = 0;
    int Height = 0;
    CurrentWidth = Width;
    CurrentHeight = Height;
    glViewport(0, 0, CurrentWidth, CurrentHeight);

}

-(void)RenderFunction { 

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();


    }

-(void)InitWindow: (int)argc: (char*[])argv:(void*)FoundRZ:(void*)FoundRD {

    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitContextVersion(4, 0);
    glutInitContextFlags(GLUT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);

    glutSetOption ( 
      GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE,
      GLUT_ACTION_GLUTMAINLOOP_RETURNS
    );

    glutInitWindowSize(CurrentWidth, CurrentHeight);
    WindowHandle = glutCreateWindow(WINDOW_TITLE_PREFIX);

    if(WindowHandle < 1) {
        fprintf(
              stderr, "ERROR: Could not create a new rendering window.\n" 
              );
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glutReshapeFunc(FoundRZ);
    glutDisplayFunc(FoundRD);


    }

-(void)Initialize: (int)argc: (char*[])argv {


    fprintf(stdout, "INFO: OpenGL Version: %s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));




}


@end
```

1.m

```
#import "header.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"hello");


    princ *GLMAIN = [[princ alloc] init];

    [GLMAIN InitValues];
    [GLMAIN InitWindow:argc:argv:[GLMAIN ResizeFunction]:[GLMAIN RenderFunction]];
    [GLMAIN Initialize:argc:argv];

    [pool drain];
    return 0;


}
```

Error :

```
$ clang -ObjC 1.m -o 1  `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -I/usr/local/lib/gcc42/gcc/x86_64-portbld-freebsd9.0/4.2.5/include -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString  -I/usr/local/GNUstep/System/Library/Headers -L/usr/local/GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries -L/usr/local/lib -lgnustep-base -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lglut -lGL
1.m:12:31: error: sending 'void' to parameter of incompatible type 'void *';
        [GLMAIN InitWindow:argc:argv:[GLMAIN ResizeFunction]:[GLMAIN RenderFunction]];
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./header.h:18:52: note: passing argument to parameter 'FoundRZ' here
-(void)InitWindow: (int)argc: (char*[])argv:(void*)FoundRZ:(void*)FoundRD;
                                                   ^
1.m:12:55: error: sending 'void' to parameter of incompatible type 'void *';
        [GLMAIN InitWindow:argc:argv:[GLMAIN ResizeFunction]:[GLMAIN RenderFunction]];
                                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./header.h:18:67: note: passing argument to parameter 'FoundRD' here
-(void)InitWindow: (int)argc: (char*[])argv:(void*)FoundRZ:(void*)FoundRD;
                                                                  ^
2 errors generated.
```

I am not using mac i am using FreeBSD but i have hope any apple developer can help with this little problem.

Comment: Try asking the question in a shorter form. It will cause people to be more likely to actually read it and respond. You will have to cut out all code not relevant to your problem in order to do that. In order to shorten the code like that, you'll have to figure out what is and isn't relevant, which might itself cause you to be able to answer your own question.

Comment: Problem #1 is choosing an awful title .. #2 is posting too much code (try a code-review site for that) and not a simple test-case .. good luck avoiding the close ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's your initWindow method.  You're passing a method that returns void to an argument that takes a void*.  The main problem here is that glut doesn't support Objective-C method calling, and requires C functions instead, so change your resizeFunction and renderFunction to C functions, then pass it and it should work.

Comment: thanks theAmateurProgrammer, I will try your suggestion but no exist other way ?

Comment: If you're using GLUT, then no.  Or you could try doing it the native way using NSOpenGLView.

Comment: I will try NSOpenGLView, i have hope of found documentation from GNUStep.
Thanks.